# A date doesn't match the format

Tags: python

Why doesn't a date match the format?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt1 = "9/1/2014 0:00"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '9/1/2014 0:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'
```

And this one either:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '9/1/2014 0:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'
```

Comment: As you will see in the answers ... maybe ... make the %y a %Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's open http://strftime.org/ and check:

```
%m  Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

so it's need to be `09`, not `9`

```
%d  Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

so it's need to be `01`, not `1`

```
%y  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

so it's need to be `14`, not `2014`

```
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

so it's need to be `00`, not `0`.

Comment: You are technically correct, but you're obfuscating the fact that the %y rather than %Y is the only thing that causes the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is,

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2012-09-1 0:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 1, 0, 0)
>>>
```